# Learning prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to learn Prolog and i have a really big problem to convert my programming knowledge to this language. I cant solve really newbie problems.

For example i have this

```
a(b(1)).
a(b(2)).
a(b(3)).
a(b(4)).
a(b(6)).
```

The exercise wants to print (using writeln(X)) all b(Y) if Y is an even number.

I can find if it is an even number using this if i am not wrong

```
a(b(X)) mod 2 =:= 0
```

but i cant understand how to check it and print all numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very basic concept in prolog is pattern matching
there are plenty of tutorials explaining it, like [this](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node16.html#sec.l2.matching) one
you might also want to check the first and rest of the second chapter.

one of the reasons i really like prolog is that i just write what i want:

I want to print all the X that have a certain attribute.
Lets describe the attribute first.

X has the attribute if
it belongs to the database
is even

```
has_attribute(X):-
    belongs_db(X),
    is_even(X).
```

X belongs in the database if there is a clause a(b(X))

```
belongs_in_db(X):-
    a(b(X)).
```

X is even if the remainder of the division with 2 is 0:

```
is_even(X):-
    0 =:= X mod 2.
```

now we can ask has_attribute(X) and prolog will reply, listing every X.
but we want all X. to do this we will use the findall/3 predicate
Find all X that have the attribute i want and put them in a list

```
findall(X,has_attribute(X),List).
```

now we have all the X in the list and we want to print them
a simple way is to just use the writeln/1:

```
writeln(List)
```

so, in the end:

```
run:-
    findall(X,has_attribute(X),List),
    writeln(List).

has_attribute(X):-
     a(b(X),
     0 =:= X mod 2.
```

on the other hand, you may want to print the numbers in some other way.
for this, you should use [recursion](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node23.html#lecture3)

if the list is empty, i'm done

```
my_print_list([]).
```

if the list has a haed and tail i'll print the first element and then the tail:

```
my_print_list([Head|Tail]):-
    writeln(Head),
    my_print_list(Tail).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
is_even(N) :-
        0 =:= N mod 2.

all_even_number :-
       a(b(X)),
       is_even(X),
       writeln(X),
       fail.
all_even_number.
```